# How to capture and display data from Observable?

Tags: ngfor, angular2-observables

I have a component named 'customer.component.ts'.
In this component's view there is a button called 'Search'.
What I I am doing is calling a web api method on this 'Search' button click which brings the data from sql db.

For this, I have a **customer.service.ts** file in which I wrote the below code -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'; 
import { Customer, CustomerContact, CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse, CustomerSearchRequestObjectClass, CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read } from '../models/customer';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost/SampleApi/api/Customer/';

searchCustomers(custReqObj: CustomerSearchRequestObjectClass): observable<CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read> {        
                    let headers = new Headers();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                    return this._http.post((this.baseUrl + 'search-customer'), JSON.stringify(custReqObj), { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json());
                }
}
```

my **customer.component.ts** has the search click function -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { strictEqual } from 'assert';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { stringify } from '@angular/core/src/facade/lang';
import { Customer, CustomerContact, CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read } from '../models/customer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';  
import { CustomerService } from '../services/customer.service';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core/src/change_detection/constants';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { error } from 'util';
import { parse } from 'path';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'customer',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/views/customer.component.html',
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private _custSvc: CustomerService) {      
    }

    ngOnInit() {}



customerSearch: CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read = new CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read();

 onCustomerSearchClick(): void {

        this._custSvc.searchCustomers(this.custSearchReqObj).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.customerSearch = data;     
            },
            err => console.log(err, 'error has occurred'),
            () => console.log(this.customerSearch)
        );
console.log(this.customerSearch);
 }
```

And below is my model class -

```
export class CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read
{
    custHeader:Customer[];
    custContact:CustomerContact[];
}
```

Both Customer and CustomerContact classes contain some properties.

And finally here is my template where I am trying to iterate through the object the table rows simply don't display any data. I have used async (AsyncPipe) also but not helping much.

```
<tr *ngFor="let custItem of customerSearch.custHeader | async; let rowIndex = index">
                                    <td>
                                        <a (click)="onCustomerItemDetailsClick(custItem.acCustomerName, rowIndex)" class="btn">{{custItem.acCustomerName}}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{custItem.acCountryId}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custItem.acAreaId}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custItem.acTel}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custItem.acFax}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custItem.acSalesContact}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a (click)="onCustomerContactItemDeleteClick(rowIndex, 'manage-customer')" class="btn" id="btnIconDelete">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Please help as I am not unable to understand what/where I am doing mistake.
Do let me know if more information is required.

Thanks in advance!
nitinthombre1991@gmail.com

EDIT -

Tried with BehaviorSubject approach, but now getting an erro like below -

[Observable error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37GXG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async pipe is used to bind observables directly to the template. So here's what you can do:

```
data$: Observable<CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read>;
search$ = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(true);

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.search$.switchMap(searchObj => this._custSvc.search...(...));
}

onCustomerSearchClick() {
  this.search$.next(true);
}
```

And the template looks like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data$ | async>...</tr>
```

So now every time your search is clicked, it will send a call to the service and the async pipe is taking care of displaying the data in the template

Comment: Thanks! But just one question here, isn't ngOnInit() fired only once when component's bound controls are initialized? I do not have that much deep idea about the BehaviourSubject though, just curious to know how it works. How 'this.search$.next(true)' forces ngOnInit() again? It will really be a great help if you could explain the processing here as well.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is a special kind of Observable where you can emit values manually by calling .next(...). So this is basically a Observable which emits every time, the search is clicked

This does not call ngOnInit again, but the data object in your onInit listens to this search observable and every time it emits, the service is called and the data is fetched

Comment: Thank you @Bene again for your generosity and help, indeed. I will try this solution.

Comment: This is how my code in ngOnInit() looks like - this.data$ = this.search$.switchMap(this.customerSearch => this._custSvc.searchCustomers(this.custSearchReqObj).subscribe(
            data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.customerSearch = data;     
                    },
                    err => console.log(err, 'error has occurred'),
                    () => console.log(this.customerSearch)
        )); Getting error - Type Observable<boolean> is not assignable to Observable>R>

Comment: You must not subscribe - this will be done through the async pipe in the template. So really just write  this.data$ = this.search$.switchMap(this.customerSearch => this._custSvc.searchCustomers(this.custSearchReqObj) and you are good to go

Comment: Still getting an error in below code line -  this.data$ = this.search$.switchMap(this.customerSearch => this._custSvc.searchCustomers(this.custSearchReqObj));   It says, Argument of type 'CustomerHeaderAndContactsResponse_Read' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: Are you sure that your service returns an Observable<CurtomerHeaderAndContactsRespone_Read> ?

Comment: Yes, service method - searchCustomers(...) returns Observable<CurtomerHeaderAndContactsRespone_Read>. Anyway, when I replace 'this.customerSearch' with 'data', no errors pop up. But then again, I get the 404 error to my service call on runtime.

Comment: oh wait, I got the error - its 
this.data$ = this.search$.switchMap(searchObj => this._custSvc.searchCustomers(this.custSearchReqObj))

searchObj ist just the emitted value from search$

btw. where is your this.custSearchReqObj? I can't find it in your code examples. Maybe you could zip the relevant files and send me a link to it? Would things make easier

Comment: Added my email in the question post. i can send required things via email. Just ping me on that one first.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bene, this indeed resolved my issue. Though I had to play around it a bit and then I downgraded my typescript version to 2.3.4. With your solution and typescript downgrade, it is working now.